# How to initialize ui elements in my ViewController extension in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, swift-extensions

I have a view controller which has a programmatically created label like below.

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupUI()
    }

    func setupUI() {
       // added an setup the view constraints.
    }
}
```

> This works properly. Then I tried to move all the UI element of the view controller to it's extension by creating a extension like below :

```
private extension MyController {

    var label: UILabel = {
      **// tried to initialize the label like this. but getting cannot use stored property in extension error**
    }()

// then tried like below
    var mylabel: UILabel! {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = "Hello"
            return label
        }

     func setupUI() {
        // with the second option I getting nil value error.
        }
}
```

> How can I initialize UI elements in viewcontroller extentions programmatically to access internally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

uielements.swift

```
extension MyController {
    static let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Hello"
        return label
    }()
}
```

myController.swift

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        view.addSubview(RootVC.myLabel)
    // Add layout constraints here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are not allowed to declare variables in extension.

> You mention that you want to initialize the UI element in the
>   extensions. of course you can do that. But, what you have in the
>   extension is a declaration not only initialization.

Have the declaration in the controller and the initialization in an extension method.